# how to remove notification bar after time interval

Tags: android

This is my code that is working fine. It shows notification bar every 20 seconds if notification remove from notification bar but i want to remove notification from notification bar every 18 second and display again every 20 seconds what do i do? how do i remove notification form notification bar??

```
 public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

AlarmManager am;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
  am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  setRepeatingAlarm();
 }

  public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
    (20 * 1000), pendingIntent);
  System.out.println("Calling Alaram...");
 }
  }



           public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationManager nm;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 nm = (NotificationManager) context
   .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 CharSequence from = "Lokesh";
 CharSequence message = "Notification Test...";
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
   new Intent(), 0);
 Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.cherry_icon,
   "Notification Test...", System.currentTimeMillis());
 notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
 nm.notify(1, notif);
}
}
```

Comment: for that you have to pass the id of last notification and use notificationManager.cancel(notificaionId);

Comment: [link] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29

Comment: give me any example  i will show my application in notifiction i want only remove my application from notification bar

Comment: As a user I'd hate to have my notification bar nagging me like this. This feels like a UI anti-pattern, please reconsider. Once a notification disappears, it shouldn't spontaneously come back. If its important enough, just leave it there until the user dismisses it.

Comment: no i want to my app show notification every 20 minutes  but problem is if user not delete current notifcation is not pop up again so i want to delete notification after some time so is triger again notification on top

Comment: I think you do not need to remove notification, because when u open it after every 20 seconds, old one will be over-right.

Comment: yes so didnot pop uo new notification is still in list so i want to first remove notification after 19 seconds so when after 1 second new notification will come is show on notification bar triger notification bar